# Show that nested intervals work for this function $f(x)=-x^3+3x^2-x-1$ with interval $[2 ; 2,5]$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, limits, roots

> Show that nested intervals work for this function $f(x)=-x^3+3x^2-x-1$
>   with interval $[2 ; 2,5]$, the starting point is $x_0=2,5$

I'm supposed to show that you can determine the zero of the function $f$ by using nested intervals.

As far as I know you need to show that $f$ is continuous in $x_0=2,5$
:

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow2,5^-}f(x)=-0,375 \text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ and } \text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\lim_{x \rightarrow2,5^+}f(x)=-0,375$$

Moreover, $f(2,5) = -0,375$

Thus $f$ is continuous at $x_0=2,5$

Now we need to show that $f(a) \leq 0$ and $f(b) \geq 0$ where $[a,b]$

In this case we have $[2;2,5]$, so

$f(2)=1$ but $1 > 0$ and $f(2,5) = -0,375 < 0$

So nested intervals don't seem to work?!

If I switched the interval, it would work. Am I allowed to switch them, so I have $[2,5;2]$ instead of $[2;2,5]$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**hint**

You just need  continuity at $[a,b] $ and the condition $$f (a) f (b)\le 0.$$

$f (2)f (2,5)\le 0$.

Comment: What does that dot mean between $f(2)$ and $f(2,5)$? Is it a multiplication sign?

Comment: @cnmesr Yes . $f (a) $ and $f (b) $ have opposite signs.